# How do I correctly align this vector?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vector

I have this vector

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fourhat}{\skew{3.4}\hat{4}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0\\
            \dot{\Theta}_{\fourhat}\\
            0
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I align the zeros such that they are centered directly above `\dot{\Theta}_{\fourhat}`?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\fourhat}{\skew{3.4}\hat{4}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0_{\phantom{\fourhat}}\\
            \dot{\Theta}_{\fourhat}\\
            0_{\phantom{\fourhat}}
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}` ?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yeah that works, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, `\centering` should not be at the point you use it, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, none of which improve on what you currently use. Here are two:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\newcommand{\fourhat}{\skew{3.4}\hat{4}}

\begin{document}

\[
  % Original
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    \dot{\Theta}_{\fourhat} \\
    0
  \end{pmatrix} \qquad
  % Suggestion 1 (eqparbox)
  \left(\begin{array}{ @{} l @{} }
    \eqmakebox[dtheta]{$0$} \\
    \eqmakebox[dtheta]{$\dot{\Theta}$}_{\fourhat} \\
    \eqmakebox[dtheta]{$0$}
  \end{array}\right) \qquad
  % Suggestion 2 (Two-column array)
  \left(\begin{array}{ @{} c @{} l @{} }
    0 \\
    \dot{\Theta} & {}_{\fourhat} \\
    0
  \end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that the width of `0` and `\dot{\Theta}` are not the same.

Comment: You are right, that's still pretty ugly. Oh well, looks like that's the way it is.